# React JS: With state, dynamically update an attribute (e.g., type) of an input that is a value in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, input, this

I have a state called `fields`, which is an array of objects. Each object has its html form, as you can see here:

```
fields: [
    {
        field: <input />,
        inputType: 'number'
    }
]
```

What I want to do is add a type attribute to the input that will update with the vale of inputType, upon a user interaction somewhere else on the app.

(I already have functions set up for the user interaction part. Basically, a user selects from a dropdown list, what they want the type to be. This drop list includes basic HTML input types, such as text, input, etc. Upon selecting a type, it will automatically update the value of inputType. I already have functions set up for that part.)

A few things I've tried, but was unsuccessful:

Idea 1:

```
fields: [
    {
        field: <input type={this.inputType} />,
        inputType: 'number'
    }
]
```

Idea 2:

```
fields: [
    {
        field: <input type={`this.inputType`} />,
        inputType: 'number'
    }
]
```

Idea 3:

```
fields: [
    {
        field: <input type={inputType} />,
        inputType: 'number'
    }
]
```

Am I wrong to think that the `this` keyword would work within an attribute in an HTML form type as a value in an object?

Thanks in advance, and let me know if any of this needs clarification.

Comment: you can change `field` to a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), which can then return the JSX element (the one shown in idea1). Alternatively, you could map your objects to an array of input elements, setting the `inputType` as the input for each element.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your first recommendation, but it is still giving me the same error message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'inputType' of undefined. I think it's because when I type in the this keyword, I'm actually pointing to the input itself, and not the object as a whole. (Found this article: [link](http://jennifermadden.com/javascript/loopThis.html#:~:text=keyword%20%22this%22%20is%20referenced%20from,form%20element%20tag%2C%20%22this.))

Comment: Your alternative solution would work, but it doesn't quite match with the rest of my app. (I didn't mention, but each of these fields are essentially drag-dropped onto an area, which then renders its field value.)

Comment: That article is slightly different since you're not working with HTML inputs, but rather JSX inputs. So in your case `this` will be the object itself your object's code is evaluated after the object has been created. I tried using your code with a getter and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/6wt2fq0h/1/

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much. I misunderstood your first comment and set inputType as a getter, and not the field. Your suggestion works perfectly now. Thanks for the jsfiddle as well.

Comment: Hi Nick (or anyone else w/ skills!), sorry to come back to this - I was wondering if there's a way to rerun the getter function that's already been rendered. I ask this because it, unfortunately, does not dynamically change upon the inputType state change. E.g., When I change the inputType from 'text' to 'number', the getter function already ran at that point, so I'd need to rerun that to reflect the new inputType. Thanks!